# Does this journalctl log look like my SCSI HDD is well and truly dead?

Tags: data-recovery, recovery

My old 2TB SCSI External HDD has died. There was a clicking sound when I tried to mount it. I was able to recover the important data, so the issue is mostly to do with if this journalctl entry looks like it's dead and irretrievably so?

```
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=259d, bcdDevice=10.05
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb 3-1: Product: My Passport 259D
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 575839314138364E304A4A33
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 19 08:36:34 lenovo kernel: scsi host3: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 259D 1005 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: scsi 3:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1005 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: ses 3:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: ses 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: ses 3:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
Mar 19 08:36:35 lenovo kernel: ses 3:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: ..................................................................................................not responding...
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 3906963456 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 19 08:38:16 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Mar 19 08:38:35 lenovo kernel: ..................ready
Mar 19 08:41:35 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
Mar 19 08:44:35 lenovo kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
```

I suppose the point might be moot anyway as since I couldn't mount nor initialise it again, I had a good go at it with a screwdriver and a hammer, but even to have an idea of what this means?

Answer (score 0):

That message means that the drive failed initializing properly.

That can be a bad cable. It can be bad power supply. It can be a broken board. It can be a multitude of reasons, from something that takes five minutes to fix for incompetent persons, to more complex faults.

We don't know.

Comment: OK, I'd call myself pretty competent. It was clicking when connected which is generally a death knell.

Comment: Could be bad power supply or power cable as well. But I must admit I fail to see the security aspect?